# How do I draw a custom pattern within the bounds of a polygon with tkinter Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have encountered an interesting problem that I am trying to solve in various ways, but there is no solution.
I have a polygon on the canvas. My task is to draw a certain pattern on this polygon without going beyond the boundaries of the polygon.
There is an idea to put a drawing on the entire canvas, then draw a polygon, and then paint over the area outside the polygon, but I do not know how to do it.

```py
self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,self.canvas.cget('width'), self.canvas.cget('height'))
self.canvas.create_polygon(self.arrCoords, fill='white', tags=('figure'))
# some function that draws pattern
# function that paints over the area outside the polygon (?)
```

Comment: If you need to draw a pattern on a polygon then include `stipple = 'gray25'` when you create it.

Comment: I'm needing custom pattern on a polygon, which contain my task, default stipple is not interssting for me))

Comment: You can use custom .xbm files instead of builtin bitmaps.